# Discriminant of odd cyclic Galois extension is not a power of 2

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, discriminant, ramification

Is there a way to prove that, given a Galois cyclic extension $\mathbb{Q} \subset F$ with odd order, there exists a prime $p \neq 2$ such that $p|\Delta_{F}$ ?
I'm actually trying to prove that the only Galois finite extensions in which $2$ is the only prime that ramifies have Galois group of even order. Proceeding by contraddiction I used Feit-Thompson to reduce to the case where $F$ is abelian over $\mathbb{Q}$ and then deduced that its Galois group is cyclic of odd order, but then I got stuck in relating this infomation with the condition that the discriminant must be a power of 2 (in order for it being the only ramified prime).

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but I would guess that Kronecker-Weber would lead to this. It says that $F$ is a subfield of $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ for some $n$. Let $n$ be minimal w.r.t. this property. Then $[F:\Bbb{Q}]$ is a factor of $\phi(n)$, so $n$ has at least one odd prime factor. The minimality of $n$ and the known discriminants of cyclotomic fields then force that prime factor to appear in the discriminant of $F$ also, doesn't it?

Comment: I follow you until the last part. How does the minimality of $n$ force that odd prime factor to appear in the discriminant of $F$?